# Suggestions for implementing relationships between two lists

Tags: workflow, list, jquery, spservices, tasks

Here is what I am trying to accomplish: I want a Sharepoint list(s) that can track received client calls and all follow-up attempts from our staff.

What I initially envisioned this would look like is two lists with a relationship between them:

> *[1]*: **INCOMING CALLS** (caller's name, number, reason for call, date/time, etc)
>   *[2]*: **CALL ATTEMPTS** (incoming call it is attached to, staff person who attempted a callback, result of callback, etc)

An **incoming call** gets logged by our staff when we get a message.  After its logged, staff will begin to make **call attempts**.  So an **incoming call** can have zero or more **call attempts**.  Each **call attempt** needs to be logged separately and connected to only one incoming call.  Once a **call attempt** is successful then the associated **incoming call** would also be completed.

Now, making these two lists and creating a look-up field is not all that challenging.  What I am not sure about, however, is how to *merge* these two lists into one cohesive system.  I would like a *view* to be able to show all the pending calls along with all the call attempts (so that staff can see which hasn't had an attempt in the longest time, etc).

My question is: what's the best way to approach this?  Would you recommend using a Workflow?  Or some jQuery from SPServices?  Some other approach I am not thinking of?

Note: am on Sharepoint 2003.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to make it hard to make it work.

Creating 2 lists with a lookup field will give you the storage solution you need.

Then you need to create views to show the info you need.  For this you need the content query web part.

This is in sp 2007, but its exactly the same in 2010
[Display data from multiple lists with the Content Query Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part-HA010174134.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this - I am going to head off and investigate your suggestion and see if it fits the bill.  I like simple.

Comment: We are running Sharepoint 2003 ... which, the system admin tells me, doesn't include this web part.  Sigh.

Comment: You shouldn't need the CQWP, though it is an option. Once you have your two lists created with the lookup relation, you can use linked list views. User selects the incoming call, and the second view will update to show the related call attempt records. 100% out of the box, all done through the UI.

Comment: This is an interesting idea - I tried playing with it but it will take a little work on my part to understand it fully.  Will definitely be looking into it, however.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Data View Web Parts (DVWPs) with AggregateDataSources to dislay the merged contents of the two lists. I have quite a few posts on my blog about how to do this:
http://sympmarc.com/?s=aggregatedatasource

BTW, SharePoint 2010 has the CQWP, but only if you have Server Standard or Enterprise, I believe.